# Two svg's below each other, only the first visible?

Tags: html, svg

I just started with SVG. simple things like

```
<svg> 
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="Gradient">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1" />
        </linearGradient>

        <mask id="Mask">    
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="url(#Gradient)"  />
        </mask>
    </defs>

    <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="#222" mask="url(#Mask)" />
</svg>
```

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMPy5/) I have this svg with on other one. However, it only shows the one first defined. Can someone explain why and how to fix this ? Thnx!

Comment: Works for me, I see 2 images, bottom one clipped. How are you testing, and what error or problem are you seeing ?

Comment: my mistake, for some reason the second svg is moved a lot downwards!

Comment: The default size for an `<svg>` is different in different browsers; in Chrome the default size is the size of the browser window (or iframe for a fiddle).